# PyGetText fails with translating a variable

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I'm trying to translate a variable during rubtime:

```
STATE = 'Not Ready'
txt = _(STATE)
```

where STATE is set elsewhere to one of several values.

The program works fine but running PyGetText fails with the message:

```
Seen unexpected token "STATE"
```

How to make PyGetText ignore this specific line?

Comment: Turns out PyGetText doesn't actually fail with this message, it just ignores this line.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me
Turns out PyGetText didn't actually fail. 
It just ignored this line just like I wanted and still created the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea: can you add brackets to your translations instead of your runtime variable, like this:

```
STATE = _("Not ready") # one for each option you have for this state string

txt = STATE
```

so you have your .po files generated with all your translation strings and then you just return the one you want?

Comment: Thanks Samuele but I actually wanted the varible to hold the untranslated string (because I use it in 'if' clauses) and translate the variable every time.

Comment: i lol'ed when i saw your "stupid me" :D anyway i still think it's better if you have all your strings already translated then returned when required (only if you plan to use those strings a lot). glad you found out about the ignore thing by yourself, didn't mention it in my answer, sorry about that :(